# TYPO3 shows both languages on one page

Tags: typo3

I use TYPO3 8 with the introduction package (bootstrap). I have added a additional language to my site. Everything works fine, but if I switch the the second language on the frontend, TYPO3 displays the content in both languages. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Found a **dirty solution** to solve it. Had the same problem here. Translations seem to work fine in backend. Database entries look good. I created many multilingual websites with TYPO3. But this time... I have a onepage and created the sections with help of HMENU. At my side, gridelements was the problem since it wrote out both languages.

In `file typo3conf/ext/gridelements/Classes/Plugin/Gridelements.php` I changed line 313 from

```
AND sys_language_uid IN (-1,0)
```

to

```
AND sys_language_uid IN (-1,' . $this->getTSFE()->sys_language_content . ')
```

I know it's not really a satisfying solution, but may help you out for now ;) Worked in TYPO3 7.6.23 and gridelements 7.1.0.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, maybe this information is useful to someone else. But, if thats your solution then the content was not created the correct way. In the tt_content.sys_language_uid column, you can enter a -1, 0 or positive integer number. -1 means all lanuages, 0 means the default system language, anything else refers to a sys_language_uid. Your initual content is set to -1 instead of 0, thats why both records are displayed, not just the localized content.

Answer (score 0):

**The page for the second language it's a page overlay ?**

First of all please check in `tt_content` the `sys_language_uid` field, would be good to check this also for the `pages` table this should be greater or equals with 0, if it's -1 this is the reason why you see the both contents.

After you've checked this try check the typoscript config:

```
config{
        linkVars = L
        sys_language_uid = 0
        sys_language_overlay = 1
        sys_language_mode = content_fallback # this recommended, if no content found for the selected language will be showed up the content from the default language 
        language = en
}

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
     config {
          sys_language_uid = 1
          language = de
          locale_all = de_DE.UTF-8
          htmlTag_setParams = lang="de" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
      }
[global]
// and so on for all languages you use
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below language configuration typoscript.

```
config {
    linkVars = L
    sys_language_mode = content_fallback
    sys_language_overlay = 1
    locale_all = en_EN
    sys_language_uid = 0
    htmlTag_langKey = en-EN
    language = en
}
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
    config.sys_language_uid = 1
    config.language = de
    config.locale_all = de_DE
    config.htmlTag_langKey = de-DE
[global]
```